# Evaluation of "andalso" arguments

Tags: erlang, boolean-expression, short-circuiting

I am new to erlang and I tried the following in the erlang shell:

```
1> ((Var1 = 13) == 13) andalso ((Var2 = 12) == 13).
false
2> Var1.
13
3> Var2.
* 1: variable 'Var2' is unbound
4>
```

Why is the *Var2* variable not bound to the value *12*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`E1 andalso E2` (since R13 i think) is equivalent to

```
case E1 of
    false -> false;
    _ -> E2
end;
```

compare to this definition I agree that Var2 should be bounded in your case.

But in general, you have no guaranty that E2 will be evaluated, so it is really unsafe to assign a value to any variable in E2.

I tried to follow the parsing of the expression in erl_parse, but I can't say if this behavior is made on purpose or not.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the Erlang evaluator. The compiler actually refuses to let this go through. Compiling this:

```
-module(t).
-compile(export_all).

main() ->
    ((Var1 = 13) == 13) andalso ((Var2 = 12) == 13),
    {Var1,
     Var2}.
```

Yields:

> t.erl:7: variable 'Var2' unsafe in 'andalso' (line 5)

Which tells you that in case the left-hand side expression would fail, the code couldn't go through as expected.

That the shell lets it go through means the evaluator running there does not properly match the compiler. It might be worth reporting to the OTP team on [erlang-bugs](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs).

Comment: interesting question. I think here it is in scope area . Ie since the next argument is checked only when necessary, the variables out of it will not be visible from the outside.  
So it's not a bug. For example, this line confirms it:                                            A =  true andalso (((R = 18) == 18) andalso R ==18).

Comment: @Atomic_alarm If it was a question of scope then it should be applied to both *Var1* and *Var2*?

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't let the use of `Var2` in `{Var1, Var2}` go through, but it does allow `((Var1 = 13) == 13) andalso ((Var2 = 12) == 13)` by itself, just as the shell evaluator does.

Comment: It is a bug if only because the compiler doesn't accept it as valid, but the evaluator does. Both should work the same in ideal circumstances.

Comment: @IGIVETERRIBLEADVICE , so they work the same,no? The compiler issues an error,also as evaluator.

Comment: @MeekaaSaangoo , yes. But first variant(Var1) is calculated in any case,i.e. it is not local.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm According to the scoping rule shouldn't the expression *Var2 = 12* be executed before the comparison to *13*? Or are you suggesting that the expression *Var2 = 12* is not executed and instead a temporary variable is created for *Var2* for the sake of comparison and the actual *Var2* is bound only when the boolean expression returns *true*?

Comment: @MeekaaSaangoo , yes, Var 2 is bound in their local scope for branches andalso. Look at the example of my first comment.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm If that is the case then why in the following expression the value of *Var2* is set to *12*?
*((Var2 = 12) == 13) andalso (Var1 = 13) == 13)).*

Comment: @MeekaaSaangoo, the first part is always executed,which means global.

Comment: It is because the evaluator, `erl_eval`, only does a code check in some cases as sometimes it is not possible to do it. One of the cases when it is not possible when this is called from the shell. From the code "The reason is that if there is a function handler present, then it is possible that there are valid constructs in Expression to be taken care of by a function handler but considerad errors by erl_lint."